# Populate a certain percentage of Java array with fixed values

Tags: java, arrays

For example I have this array

```
int[] array = new int[size];
```

I want to populate 30 % of the array with 2 and another 70% with 8 based on its size. How can I do it.

Edit: there can be more than 2 numbers with their certain percentage attached.

Comment: You just need to calcualte percentage value of `size`

Comment: Yeah, but how can I randomly add those values and make sure they are being populated based on their fixed percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than two percentage count, then store it in an array, also store the values to be filled in an separate array and then you can apply following logic.

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int p[] = new int[3];
    p[0] = 10;//%
    p[1] = 20;//%
    p[2] = 70;//%

    int value[] = new int[3];
    value[0] = 1;//fill 1 to first 10%
    value[1] = 2;//fill 2 to first 20%
    value[2] = 3;//fill 3 to first 70%

    int size = 100;
    int a[] = new int[size];

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<(size*p[i])/100;j++){
            a[count] = value[i];
            ++count;
        }

    }
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Here `p` is percentage array and `value` is value array, which specifies the values to be filled in corresponding percentage part of the final array. The output of above code will be 10 elements valued 1, 20 elements valued 2 and rest will be valued 3.

Here I've taken 3 percentage value, you can replace three with `n` and populate array. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two loops for example :

```
int size = 10;
int[] array = new int[size];
int percent30 = (int) (size * 0.3);

for (int i = 0; i < percent30; i++) {
    array[i] = 2;
}

for (int i = percent30; i < size; i++) {
    array[i] = 8;
}
```

If the size is 10 the result is

```
[2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
 -------  -------------------
   30%           70%
```

---

> Is it possible to make this work with more than 2 numbers? I mean
>   there can be 3 or more numbers with their percentage attached to it.
>   How can the array be populated then?

In this case I would like to create a method which will fill my array for example :

```
public static int[] fillArray(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex, int number) {
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        array[i] = number;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Then you can all it many times with different values for example :

```
array = fillArray(array, 0, (int) (size * 0.3), 2);
array = fillArray(array,(int) (size * 0.3), (int) (size * 0.5) , 8);
array = fillArray(array,(int) (size * 0.5), size , 10);
```

---

### Another solution :

Or you can create a class which hold this information :

```
class Information {
    int startIndex;
    int endIndex;
    int number;

    public Information(int startIndex, int endIndex, int number) {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Then you can use :

```
//Fill the information in an array
Information[] information = {
        new Information(0, (int) (size * 0.3), 2),
        new Information((int) (size * 0.3), (int) (size * 0.5), 8),
        new Information((int) (size * 0.5), size, 10)
};
//then loop over this info and fill the array
for (Information info : information) {
    array = fillArray(array, info);
}
```

Your method can be also changed :

```
public static int[] fillArray(int[] array, Information into) {
    for (int i = into.startIndex; i < into.endIndex; i++) {
        array[i] = into.number;
    }
    return array;
}
```

---

### Best solution

I find that `Arrays` have already a method [**Arrays.fill**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-int-int-) which take :

```
public static void fill(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int val)
```

In this case you can just use :

```
for (Information info : information) {
    Arrays.fill(array, info.startIndex, info.endIndex, info.number);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this work with more than 2 numbers? I mean there can be 3 or more numbers with their percentage attached to it. How can the array be populated then?

Answer (score 1):

Simply calculate the percentage and fill the array.

example:

```
int[] array = new int[size];
int percent1 = Math.floor(size*0.3); //percentage of 2
for(int i =0; i < percent1; i++){
   arr[i] = 2;
}
for(int i =percent1; i < size; i++){
   arr[i] = 2;
}
```